# Can an isometry of the hyperbolic plane that maps a circle to a disjoint circle have a fixed point?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Can an isometry of the hyperbolic plane that maps a circle (centred on the real line) to a disjoint circle (also centred on the real line) have a fixed point?

By disjoint, I mean that the two circles have no points in common.

If we were considering Moebius transformations with complex coefficients then of course this would be true. But I can't decide the truth when the coefficients are real.

Comment: By circle you mean maximal geodesics right? It does so happen that hyperbolic circles depicted in the upper half-plane model are also Euclidean circles, but those semicircles positioned on the real axis in hyperbolic geometry are more analogous to the straight lines in Euclidean geometry (which to be fair are considered "generalized circles"). Just making sure.

Comment: Yes - I am talking about complete geodesics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example is the matrix $\pmatrix{0 &1\\-1 & 1}$ acting by the fractional linear transformation $f(z) = 1 / (-z+1)$. The restriction of $f$ to the upper half plane is an isometry, it fixes the point $p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$ in the upper half plane, and the two points $p$ and its complex conjugate $\bar p$ are the only two points in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ that are fixed by $f$.

In fact for any fractional linear transformation $f$ and any point $q \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $q \ne f(q) \in \mathbb{C}$, by continuity there exists $\epsilon>0$, and a circle $C$ centered on $q$ and contained in the Euclidean $\epsilon$-ball $B(q,\epsilon)$ whose image $f(C)$ is a circle contained in the Euclidean $\epsilon$-ball $B(f(q),\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ is chosen so tiny that $B(q,\epsilon) \cap B(f(q),\epsilon) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear! So every elliptic element has this property!